# django ApiView login returns 404

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I am having problems with my login API view. When trying to login I get a POST 404 but I know the url path is correct because if I put a simple GET request in the view it returns data. There are still some rough parts of my code but I thought this would work.

**login.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import status
from apiV1.v1.accounts.models.user import User
from apiV1.v1.accounts.serializers.user import UserSerializerLogin


# login
class LoginView(APIView):
    authentication_classes = ()
    permission_classes = ()

    @staticmethod
    def post(request):
        user = get_object_or_404(User, email=request.data.get('email'))
        user = authenticate(username=user.email, password=request.data.get('password'))
        if user:
            serializer = UserSerializerLogin(user)
            return Response(serializer.data)
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

**serializers.py**

```
class UserSerializerLogin(UserSerializer):
    token = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    @staticmethod
    def get_token(user):
        """
        Get or create token
        """

        token, created = Token.objects.get_or_create(user=user)
        return token.key

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'profile', 'role', 'token')
```

**POST**

```
{
    "email": "admin",
    "password": "password"
}
```

Comment: show your post data and result of `User.objects.filter(email=EMAIL_FROM_POST)`

Comment: I added the post but if you could expand where you would want that edit

Comment: and what about `User.objects.filter(email="admin")`?

Comment: I am really sorry...but I do not understand where you would want me to put `User.objects.filter(email="admin")`

Comment: `./manage.py shell` next `from apiV1.v1.accounts.models.user import User;User.objects.filter(email="admin")` and show us the resutl

Comment: yeah....I am not a very smart man.... I wasnt entering a email...I was entering a username. Everything seems to work now.

Comment: glad to help, you!

Comment: thank you very much